# Building a solution file using MSBuild Vs inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have a question regarding the difference I have noticed when building a solution file using MSBuild from command line and when doing it inside Visual Studio 2013 Update 4. The solution file I am using contains a lot of projects.

**Case: Using MSBuild**

After successfully building the solution file, if I try to build it again, MSBuild notifies me that the projects are up-to-date and it doesn't try to compile any source files, which is evidently the expected behavior. Nevertheless, it actually tries to execute or goes through the targets in the Build step trying to determine whether the Output files are out-of-date and this occurs for every project that is existent in the solution. Even though it doesn't build the solution again, the process of checking time stamps of files for each project actually takes quite a long time.

**Case: Using Visual Studio**

When doing it inside Visual Studio, after a successful build, if I try to build the solution again, then it automatically notifies me that the projects are up-to-date. It actually takes few seconds to return this output. Looking at the build output, I noticed Visual Studio doesn't really execute targets in the Build step to conclude that the projects are up-to-date. So I figured it must be using something different to check the statuses of the projects.

I really want to bridge the performance gap between these two "worlds". I would appreciate any help or hints in regards to how Visual Studio is performing this check or ways I could implement something similar in MSBuild.

Cheers!

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't build anything, it uses MSBuild to get the job done.  How long file stamp checking takes is purely based on how long it takes to find the files back on the disk.  Which *seems* faster when you build in VS, it checked files when you loaded the project so the info is still fresh in the file system cache.  Specific to C++, the /Gm option can speed up builds.  VS never forgets to use the /M option for MSBuild.  In general, if you want to go faster then be sure to buy more RAM and get an SSD.

Comment: I have enough amount of RAM and am using an SSD. Is it not possible to replicate the same kind of performance when building the solution using msbuild on command line? The thing I noticed is that when building already up-to-date projects in VS, it doesn't output anything concerning the execution of targets of the Build step where it checks the file stamps, even when having the output in Diagnostic mode. That is why I asked if VS was using some other mechanism to check the statuses of projects. Or is it just the case that this performance increase is due to the initial loading of projects?